# Matplotlib: datetime-based linecollection in interactive jupyter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot a collection of tens of thousands of line segments in a matplotlib interactive plot in a Jupyter notebook. The problem I have is that

- the x-values are datetimes (datetime64[ns], basically POSIX timestamps)
- `LineCollection`s can only be based on numbers
- when leaving the x-axis of the plot to be numbers, when I zoom the plot, the x-axis nicely adjusts in scale to the zoom. However, the x-axis values are uninformative. When formatting the x-axis to informative datetime values, this information is lost when zooming.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections  as mc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

%matplotlib nbagg # interactive plot in jupyter notebook

x = np.array([['2018-03-19T07:01:00.000073810', '2018-03-19T07:01:00.632164618'],
       ['2018-03-19T07:01:00.000073811', '2018-03-19T07:01:00.742295898'],
       ['2018-03-19T07:01:00.218747698', '2018-03-19T07:01:00.260067814'],
      ['2018-03-19T07:01:01.218747698', '2018-03-19T07:01:02.260067814'],
      ['2018-03-19T07:01:02.218747698', '2018-03-19T07:01:02.260067814'],
      ['2018-03-19T07:01:02.218747698', '2018-03-19T07:01:02.260067814']],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
y = np.array([[12355.5, 12355.5],
       [12363. , 12363. ],
       [12362.5, 12362.5],
       [12355.5, 12355.5],
       [12363. , 12363. ],
       [12362.5, 12362.5]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
segs = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 2))
segs[:, :, 1] = y
segs[:, :, 0] = mdates.date2num(x)
lc = mc.LineCollection(segs)
ax.set_xlim(segs[:,:,0].min(), segs[:,:,0].max())
ax.set_ylim(segs[:,:,1].min()-1, segs[:,:,1].max()+1)
ax.add_collection(lc)
```

Now, zooming works fine -- the x-axis scale adjusts with the zoom -- but the x-axis values don't tell me anything useful, i.e. the precise time I'm currently looking at. To remedy this I tried to e.g. do:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.SecondLocator())
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MicrosecondLocator()) # this causes the plot not to display
Fmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%S")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(Fmt)
```

Now clearly zooming doesn't work fine since matplotlib doesn't know how format the finer ticks. So if I zoom sufficiently -- which I need to do -- I basically have no ticks on the x-axis.

Is there a way to address this? One way I could think of is to be able to setup a callback that gets called when the plot zooms, and adjust the format of the x-axis. But as far as I could find, this is not possible.

Comment: Matplotlib date Locators don't do well sub-millisecond because they are floating point days since 01-01-0000.  You are better off converting to floating point seconds from some reference date closer to your current date: `(x - np.datetime64('2019-03-01')).astype(np.float)) / 24/ 3600` and plotting that....

Comment: Thanks, but that would still be cumbersome, e.g. if I use seconds since start of day I'd have to mentally convert e.g. 12352.723491 to the actual time, which is not what I want. One workaround I found is to set `ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f')`. Then, at least the tooltip info will display the precise time. Or, if the x-axis values are the raw timestamps: `ax.fmt_xdata = lambda x: pandas.to_datetime(x)`

Comment: ... dates *are* cumbersome!  You could pretty easily write a formatter and locator that deals with your floats based on the ones in matplotlib, but the ones in matplotlib won't get you down to nanoseconds because there aren't enough bits in a 64-bit float to do that the way matplotlib natively handles dates.

Comment: Nanoseconds aren't the problem, I'd be fine with microseconds. The issue is that if I use a formatter, it doesn't work when zooming the plot. I.e. when zooming a lot I need microseconds, but the intial plot is based on the entire day so using microseconds causes the plot not to display because Locator.MAXTICKS is exceeded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the main problem is currently to get just any useful ticks and labels on your plot. The default way to do this would be

```
loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
fmt = mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
```

This would automatically choose useful tick locations for you and is correct down to some microseconds; below that, ticking may become inaccurate due to floating point restrictions.

Meaning, if you need customized or more accurate tick locations you will need to write your own locator and/or change the units of your data (e.g. to "seconds since midnight").

Comment: Excellent, that worked thanks. It now adjusts the scale automatically when zooming. Note that in order for this to work, the x-axis does need to be in the matplotlib numeric date format (i.e. converted with `mdates.date2num`)